# Spell checker or search for best fit for a word/phrase?

Tags: search, spell-checking, aspell

Can anyone help me figure out a way to replace something like "credits card" with the correct spelling of "credit card".  Or "hame imprvment" with "home improvement".  I have a custom word/phrase list that I would like to find the closest match for a misspelled word or phrase.  I do not want to include a master dictionary, rather have my own master word list only.  I tried to use aspell but could not figure out how to use just my own dictionary without the master english dictionary.

Thanks for any help,
John

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered "agrep".  It works for me.

Comment: agreap?? could you please give more details on this